# Woocommerce removes shipping labels from cart and checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am selling services using Woocommerce and have enabled shipping address on checkout using snippet, which works fine.

In order to avoid error on checkout, I have to enable free shipping. I do not want the label Shipping: Free Shipping to be shown on Cart and Checkout. Tried using the following snippet, but it didn't work. Please help.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'remove_shipping_label', 10, 2 );

function remove_shipping_label( $label, $method ) {
$new_label = preg_replace( '/^.+:/', '', $label );

return $new_label;
}
```

Comment: If you are selling services why do you need a shipping address? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: The service involves sending packages.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable shipping in the woocommerce settings.

To force clients to fill in their adress to ship your products to, copy and paste the following code in to your functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address', '__return_true', 50 );
```

So basically your free shipping label goes away because you disabled shipping and the costs etc but clients still need to fill in the address fields.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your help. However, the code returns error: syntax error, unexpected '', 50 );' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE)

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: BTW, the product is set to virtual. I tried using add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping', '__return_true' ); which shows the shipping address fields on checkout, but need to enable Shipping.

Comment: I have a website with the same settings and it works fine. Can you explain what you mean with "need to enable shipping" or upload some screenshots?

Comment: In order to show Shipping Address on the checkout for virtual product, I got to use the filter above and I have to enable Shipping Calculations under Woocommerce. If I disable shipping, it wouldn't show the shipping address on checkout.